# Editing a row in a gridview by the use of the click into button event

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have this **gridview** in my application :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="تحديث البيانات"  OnClick="gv_RowEditing"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="السعر الأقصى">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="mintxt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("prix max")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="السعر الأدنى"  >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="maxtxt" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("prix min")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Datvente" HeaderText="التاريخ" SortExpression="Datvente" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="NomAdh" HeaderText="الإسم و اللقب" SortExpression="NomAdh" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CodAdh" HeaderText="المنخرط" SortExpression="CodAdh" />

             <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="Ref" runat="server"  Value='<%#Eval("Ref")%>'/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>


        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

The event of the click into button :

```
Protected Sub gv_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)


        Try
            Dim min As Double = Double.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells("mintxt").ToString())
            Dim max As Double = Double.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells("maxtxt").ToString())
            Dim reference As String = Double.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells("Ref").ToString())
            If min > max Then
                avis2.Text = "الصيغة خاطئة"
                Return
            End If
            DataAccessLayer.updatetraitementprix(min, max, reference)
            avis2.Text = ""
            FillingGrid(Session("region"), Session("date"), Session("speculation"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            avis2.Text = "الصيغة خاطئة"
            GridView1.Visible = True
            Return
        End Try
     Me.FillingGrid(Session("region"), Session("date"), Session("speculation"))
    End Sub
```

I need to get the value of the column `Ref` and the new values of fields `maxtxt` and `mintxt` . but it didn't work

[image: err]

- What are the reasons of this problem?
- How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely need of `RowEditing` event. What you are doing is firing a simple `OnClick` event. So make these changes.

Markup ( Name change so that you may not confuse it with RowEditing event )

```
<asp:TemplateField >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" 
            Text="تحديث البيانات" 
            OnClick="Savebtn_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind

```
Protected Sub Savebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim clickedRow As GridViewRow = CType(btn.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

    Dim minTextBox As TextBox = CType(clickedRow.FindControl("mintxt"), TextBox)
    Dim maxTextBox As TextBox = CType(clickedRow.FindControl("maxtxt"), TextBox)
    Dim refHidden As HiddenField = CType(clickedRow.FindControl("Ref"), HiddenField)

    Dim min As Double = Double.Parse(minTextBox.Text)
    Dim max As Double = Double.Parse(maxTextBox.Text)
    Dim reference As Double = Double.Parse(refHidden.Value)

    'rest of the code goes here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the TextBox controls are inside of TemplateField's, you have to use [`Control#FindControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find them. Be aware of the Cell's index for each control.

```
Dim tbMin As TextBox = CType(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).FindControl("mintxt"), TextBox)
Dim min As Double = Double.Parse(tbMin.Text)
```

Comment: Sorry but the property Text didn't exists

Comment: I do this this but i get this error `The object reference is not set to an instance of an object.` in the first line

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. When using FindControl we need to cast the object. Try GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("mintxt") or changing the index. Check SelectedRow as well.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in that line and debug the code. You should be able to find the TextBox, either with GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[X]. or GridView1.SelectedRow. FindControl("control_name")

Comment: Breakpoints in VS: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KiqiBKId6eY and do what I said in my previous comment. I am sure you will find out the bug!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is actually because the **selectedrow** is **nothing**, so you first need to get the current selected row then access all the controls in that row.

Please replace your code to the following:

```
Protected Sub gv_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Try
            'First, get the saveBtn
            Dim saveBtn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

            'Next, get the selected row of that button
            Dim selectedRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(saveBtn.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)

            'Now you can access all the controls of that row
            Dim mintxt As TextBox = DirectCast(selectedRow.FindControl("mintxt"), TextBox)
            Dim maxtxt As TextBox = DirectCast(selectedRow.FindControl("mintxt"), TextBox)
            Dim Ref As HiddenField = DirectCast(selectedRow.FindControl("Ref"), HiddenField)

            'Get the values of the controls
            Dim min As Double = Double.Parse(mintxt.Text)
            Dim max As Double = Double.Parse(maxtxt.Text)
            Dim refVal As Double = Double.Parse(Ref.Value)

            If min > max Then
                avis2.Text = "الصيغة خاطئة"
                Return
            End If
            DataAccessLayer.updatetraitementprix(min, max, refVal)
            avis2.Text = ""
            FillingGrid(Session("region"), Session("date"), Session("speculation"))
        Catch ex As Exception
            avis2.Text = "الصيغة خاطئة"
            GridView1.Visible = True
            Return
        End Try
        Me.FillingGrid(Session("region"), Session("date"), Session("speculation"))

    End Sub
```

Comment: +1: great answer. but please note that its not the current selected row, its just the clicked row. `CommandName="Select"` is different altogether.